# SharePoint 2013 Document Library - open pdfs in a new window & centre on screen

Tags: 2013, document-library, pdf

I'm using the following code snip to open pdf files from a SP2013 document library in a new window.

I'm hoping someone might know how I can update the code to make the resulting new window open in the centre of the screen?

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        if(window.location.href.toUpperCase().indexOf("/xxxx/SITEPAGES/")>0)
    {
        
        //on category click
        $( ".ms-gb" ).click(function() {
    
        
        setTimeout(function(){ openLinkinNewWindowForms(); }, 1000);
        });
    }
 });
$(window).on('load', function() {
setTimeout(function(){ openLinkinNewWindowForms(); }, 1000);
});

function openLinkinNewWindowForms()
{
    //alert("clicked");
        
        //$("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0").find("a.ms-listlink.ms-draggable").each(function(){    

$(".ms-listlink").each(function(){  
//alert("inside function");     
    
if($(this).attr("href"))
{
    var targetValue=$(this).attr("href");

    //if(targetValue.indexOf(".aspx")>0)
        //{
            var anchorTag = $(this)[0];
            var linkUrl=anchorTag.href;
            anchorTag.removeAttribute("href");
            var customClick =  "window.open('"+linkUrl+"','_blank','resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=800,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes')";
                        //window.resizeTo( 1200,800 );
            anchorTag.setAttribute("onclick", customClick);
            anchorTag.setAttribute("style","cursor:pointer");
        //}
}
    });

}   

</script>
```

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try opening the window with **top** and **left** parameters as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window with some specifications.</p>

<button onclick="myPopup('https://www.w3schools.com', 'web', 1100, 500);">Open Qries.com</button>

<script>

function myPopup(myURL, title, myWidth, myHeight) {

            var left = (screen.width - myWidth)/2;
            var top = (screen.height - myHeight)/4;           
            
            var myWindow = window.open(myURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + myWidth + ', height=' + myHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
         }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen) and [geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-center-a-popup-window-on-screen/)

### Updating function openLinkinNewWindowForms() to open pdfs in a new windows.

Changes: New lines added and one existing line has been commented out.
Replace the **entire** function with the script provided here.
It has been verified with Chrome

```
function openLinkinNewWindowForms()
{
    //alert("clicked");
        
        //$("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0").find("a.ms-listlink.ms-draggable").each(function(){    

$(".ms-listlink").each(function(){  
//alert("inside function");     
    
if($(this).attr("href"))
{
    var targetValue=$(this).attr("href");

    //if(targetValue.indexOf(".aspx")>0)
        //{
            var anchorTag = $(this)[0];
            var linkUrl=anchorTag.href;
            anchorTag.removeAttribute("href");

            //**Begin new Lines of Code**
           
            var width=800;
            var height=600;
            var left = (screen.width - width)/2;
            var top = (screen.height - height)/4;
            var customClick =  "window.open('"+linkUrl+"','_blank','resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=800,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes" + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left +"')";
           
           //**End of new Lines of Code**
            
            //**commented out this line
           //var customClick =  "window.open('"+linkUrl+"','_blank','resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=800,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes')";
                        //window.resizeTo( 1200,800 );
            anchorTag.setAttribute("onclick", customClick);
            anchorTag.setAttribute("style","cursor:pointer");
        //}
}
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matiur. Much appreciated. My existing code snip is effective in opening the documents in a new window. I'm not an experienced coder, so was hoping someone could help update my existing snip to centre the documents on opening. Are you able to suggest how my snip can be updated to include the top and left parameters at all?

Comment: What types (docx, pdf, gif etc) of documents are in your library?  I was just stating how the window.open can center the new window. I will verify your code and post my response later today

Comment: Update the function that will open pdf in a new window positioned at the center. Let me know if you have any questions. You need to replace the entire function with the code provided

Comment: That works perfectly Matiur. Thank you so much for the help and apologies for the delayed reply.